# Proving there is a pair of congruent triangles

Tags: geometry

[image: Proving there is a pair of congruent triangles]

I am a school teacher, got into this problem teching congruent triangles, and wasnt able to prove that triangles GFE and GIH are congruent kowing that G is over EI and HF. I only noticed angles EGF and IGH are equal. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What attempts have you done so far? Where are you stuck? Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to show your work and review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for tips on providing context in your question to better assist the community.

Comment: *"[I] wasnt able to prove that triangles GFE and GIH are congruent."* ... That's good, because those triangles needn't be congruent.

Comment: Is FH=EI ? Or is EG=GH ?

Answer (score 4):

[Assuming $\overline{EG}$ and $\overline{HG}$ have the same length.]

Here is an illustration of a counterexample. On the left, I've shown two ways $\overline{EF}$ can be positioned while (a) still having $F$ being collinear with $\overline{HG}$, and (b) having the same length as $\overline{HI}$.

[image]

---

It is possible that one is meant to interpret that $\overline{EI}$ and $\overline{FH}$ have the same length (even though the tick marks on the picture don't seem to be positioned in that way). If so, then the following argument can prove congruence:

> $\triangle EFI$ and $\triangle HIF$ are congruent by SSS. Thus $\angle E$ and $\angle H$ are the same. You can then conclude that $\triangle EFG$ and $\triangle HIG$ are congruent by SAS.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer in the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: When proving (2), how do you know $\angle EFM = \angle HIN$?

Comment: Triangles EFM and HIN can be proved by RHS congruence
EM=HN (CPCT),  EF = HI, <EMF=<HNI

Comment: I see, thanks. I think the error is actually in the step $GF=GI$. The endpoint $M$ of the altitude $EM$ need not lie between $F$ and $G$, e.g. if $F$ is obtuse. See my answer. In particular, it is possible that the length of $GF$ is the difference between the lengths of $MG$ and $MF$, rather than the sum.